# Two answers on same question from same user

Tags: discussion, support, answers, duplicate-answers, deletion

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516267/google-charts-dashboard-hide-columns/) is good (7 votes) and very old (3 years old), and has just been recently answered by [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4164622/jay), a user with 1 reputation. Their answer was of a low quality... or should I say answers?

[Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4164622/jay) answered twice, with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35474978/5583289/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35475143/5583289/), both with the similar code, the first with some explanation text (which was badly formatted and didn't really make sense).

It seems as if [Jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4164622/jay) wanted to edit their answer, but instead created a new answer. His explanation for this was:

> I needed to provide the complete function as a solution and not incomplete answers. Trying to make life easier

So my question is this: how do we deal with this?

Comment: I left a comment but beyond that I don't have high hopes...

Comment: @rene, though is there a better way to deal with this? _I don't have high hopes..._

Comment: There may be:  inspect the second post, see if really is an edit on the older post, edit it in manually [and with 20K+ reputation, vote to delete the other answer].

Comment: @Makoto, I don't have +20,000 reputation, so would you be able to do that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Users that post a new answer to fix an earlier answer are often used to forum sites with threaded discussions where they don't have the option to edit their post.

It is not forbidden to post multiple answers but each answer has to be judged on its own merits and moderated accordingly. If the post isn't up to our quality standards the options are:

- Down vote to signal to the OP and the community that the post is not good enough.
- Edit to improve the quality
- Leave a comment to explain the action needed by the OP, for example:

  > You better re-visit the [help] center to learn that you can [edit] posts. Stack Overflow is NOT a forum with threaded discussions
- Flag (but only if the answer is gibberish or [not an attempt to answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer))
- Delete vote (if you have > 20K reputation).

In this case myself and [Tunaki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1743880/tunaki) edited the newer answer so it actually works with a Stack Snippet. And I down voted the other answer so three users with 20K could delete vote it.

Pr0blam solved.

Comment: @Tunaki Did you really `-1`? xD. Rene, perfect answer :).

Comment: @Mirabilis He probably got upset because he started to investigate: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28864180#28864180 when there really wasn't much left to do ...

Comment: @Mirabilis, FYI, no, Tunaki didn't really downvote.

Comment: @DougGlancy, my I ask why [-1 should be "Pr0bl3m solved](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317300/two-answers-on-same-question-from-same-user/317303?noredirect=1#comment311218_317303) got **12** votes?

Comment: @Mirabilis, I don't know. Humor of some sort, I'd guess.

Comment: @DougGlancy, I thought that Stack Overflow voted on quality, not humor. (Sorry, Tunaki ;) ).

Comment: @Mirabilis well, [meta is murder](http://blog.codinghorror.com/meta-is-murder) and we [hate fun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/268583/158100) but on meta the atmosphere is a bit different as some of the regulars seem to know each other in one way or the other.

Comment: @DougGlancy How can you know that `Tunaki didn't really downvote` :O

Comment: @Ajeets there are, at moment of posting this comment, no down votes on my answer ...